# Abnormal behaviour in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios4

I was developing an application based on navigation controllers and tableviews. After working for two days, I experienced abnormal behaviour in xcode. For debugging errors, I used 'NSLog()' and alert view. But it was not executed while debugging. Some codes which i changed was not shown in the execution. Then it got worse, even it didn't recognize break points inside the code. Even I closed the application and restarted it. Still it was giving the same problem. Then I deleted the build folder. And then it became normal. Why this happened? Whats the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general strategy, when I see weirdness like that during development, I do a 'clean all' (equivalent to deleting the build directory) and rebuild. It's not a guaranteed fix, but sometimes it helps.

Comment: Which is, by the way, essentially the same thing as deleting the build folder. Dependency tracking can be tricky, and when the IDE misses, it might not build something which needs to be, which can cause very screwy errors. Clean all is a simple thing to ensure you are starting with the freshest of everything.